# Interview - Sorting based on start and end value

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I got this question in one of my interview. There was an array of objects which was associated with start value and end value. The count associated with each object is the number of other objects with greater start time and lesser end time. So I had to find the count associated with each object.

I came up with O(n^2) solution, where first I sorted on start value and then checked each object's end value with the end values of next objects to get count. Can there be better algorithm to tackle this problem.

Comment: I think if you had a code for what you did , you could have asked this question in Code Review SE to review your code or to find a better approach. Even Programmers SE may also help.

Comment: @ViniVasundharan CodeReview is for reviewing code, not algorithm ideas.

Comment: @n.m. : Oh. I thought it would help with the best programming practices.

Comment: @ViniVasundharan: It can/does (especially if you ask for help in that direction). You're still likely to get some fairly straightforward reviews of the code itself, but you stand a decent chance of getting algorithmic advice as well.

Answer (score 3):

I did't find a simple way to solve it, maybe a little complex.

I came up with an `O(nlogn)` solution. Like your solution, first I sort on start value but in **descending** order. Then applying for a new array `a[]` keeping the **occurrence number** of **end** value (That is, when meeting an object (start, end), make `a[end]` plus one). Then traverse the object array, for object `i` with `(start, end)`, we just need add **sum(a[i] | 0<=i<=end)** to final answer, then update array `a` with `a[end] ++`, for the `sum()` query, we can use [Fenwick tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree) or [Segment tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) to calculate every query in `O(logn)`, so the total complexity is `O(nlogn)`.